# How can I copy selected polygon features to a polyline feature class with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, vb.net

I would like to copy selected polygon features to a polyline feature class. (Similar to how polygon features can be copied and pasted inside an edit session in ArcMap)

Until recently I've been using the pPolygon2:ExteriorRingCount, pPolygon2:InteriorRingCount method - iterating through the polygon rings and converting them into polylines and so on...  As described in [**this post**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50322/is-ipolygon2-queryexteriorringsex-method-not-working-in-arcgis-version-10-1-sp1) I have a suspicion that the pPolygon2:ExteriorRingCount method might not be working in ArcObjects 10.1 (VS 2010 Express, VB.NET)

Although this approach has been working flawlessly until version 10.0 perhaps I am over-complicating things.  **What is the best approach for copying polygon features to a polyline feature class with ArcObjects?**

Comment: Are you wanting to preserve all coordinates (including interior rings) when you convert your polygons to polylines?

Comment: I wonder if you might just use geoprocessing for this: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000039000000

Comment: Good Idea @blah238 but this seems to be only available in the Advanced license.  I would like this to work under all license levels. SHould have mentioned that in the post.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - for each polygon feature I would like to obtain all rings and convert to simple polylines and merge to a a single polyline myltigeometry so that I can also copy over the attributes (if the fields exist in the target feature class). Not 100% sure what you mean by preserving coordinates of interior rings.

Comment: Did you try [ITopologicalOperator.Boundary](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003v7000000)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - I have not and that looks exactly like what I am looking for!  Can you please make that an answer. I will try this as soon as I can.